# Help me xml parsing in php

Tags: php, xml

I have an xml response from zoho recruit API. I just need to parse it get values of a few attributes and nodes(whatever you call it). And then update them and submit back. The xml is given below.
Like If i want to check what is first name it should return TEst1
and when I want to update it I should get updated and then I have to save it in a string format.
Help me to figure this out.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>

<response uri="/ats/private/xml/Candidates/getRecords">
<result>
<Candidates>
<row no="1">
<FL val="RESUMEID"><![CDATA[93327000000109297]]></FL>
<FL val="Modified by"><![CDATA[Not specified]]></FL>
<FL val="Modified time"><![CDATA[Yesterday]]></FL>
<FL val="Candidate ID"><![CDATA[677]]></FL>
<FL val="First name"><![CDATA[TEst1]]></FL>
<FL val="Last name"><![CDATA[TEst2]]></FL>
<FL val="Residental Address"><![CDATA[TESTing res address]]></FL>
<FL val="Email ID"><![CDATA[test1@email.com]]></FL>
<FL val="Mobile Phone"><![CDATA[123456789]]></FL>
<FL val="Created On"><![CDATA[Yesterday]]></FL>
<FL val="Owner"><![CDATA[0]]></FL>
<FL val="Source"><![CDATA[Embed]]></FL>
<FL val="Employment Preference"><![CDATA[Contract (Full Time), Permanent (Full Time), Contract (Part Time), Permanent (Part Time)]]></FL>
<FL val="Cover Letter" type="url" url="https://recruit.zoho.com/ats/viewPhoto?filename=tVmTJJk2PIGQSgJSgY2fTzZfMgYE*W1ZBQ.KWiE6q68UOoUiAiY8ElcJtvxybS4bvD4mCWuA8aE-"><![CDATA[samplecoverletter.txt]]></FL>
<FL val="Total work exp (year)"><![CDATA[10]]></FL>
<FL val="Current Role"><![CDATA[Administrative Officer]]></FL>
<FL val="Current Role if Other"><![CDATA[current_role_if_other]]></FL>
<FL val="Current Employer/Customer"><![CDATA[Current_employer_name]]></FL>
<FL val="Skill sets"><![CDATA[skill_sets_goes_here]]></FL>
<FL val="Roles"><![CDATA[Consultant, 93327000000068819, Administrative Officer, Application Developer, Business Analyst, Change Manager, Business Development, Chief Technology Officer, Chief Information Officer, Chief Executive Officer, Data Analyst, Director, IT Manager, Implementation Mgr, Functional Analyst, PMO Manager, Other, Network Admin, Portfolio Manager, Program Manager, Project Admin, Project Manager (Jnr), Project Lead, Project Director, Project Manager (Mid), Project Manager (Snr/Principal), Project Officer, Project Scheduler, Service Delivery Mgr, Release Manager, Quality Manager, Solutions Architect, Systems / Technical Analyst, Systems Administrator, Technical Support, Technical Architect, Systems Engineer, Test Analyst, Test Manager]]></FL>
<FL val="Role (if "Other")"><![CDATA[Role_other]]></FL>
<FL val="Industries"><![CDATA[93327000000068909, 93327000000070037, Aviation, Consulting, Contact Centres, Construction / Engineering, Council, Defense, Education, Energy, Finance/Banking, Gaming, Government, Health / Medical, Hospitality, ICT, Insurance, Manufacturing, Media, Mining, Other, Rail, Retail, Phamacetical, Telecommunications, Transportation, Utilities]]></FL><FL val="Expected Rate/Salary"><![CDATA[147852369]]></FL>
<FL val="Qualifications, Credentials, Memberships"><![CDATA[93327000000068871, 93327000000101075, AABA Membership, Agile PM Certification, AIPM   Membership, CMI Membership, Degree, IIBA Membership, ITIL, Masters Degree, MBA, MSP, PMI Membership, PMP, PRINCE2, RegPM]]></FL>
<FL val="Additional Information"><![CDATA[addational_information_goes_here]]></FL>
<FL val="Attach resume" type="url" url="https://recruit.zoho.com/ats/viewPhoto?filename=tVmTJJk2PIGQSgJSgY2fTzZfMgYE*W1ZBQ.KWiE6q69pGZ2uc5*.nlcJtvxybS4bvD4mCWuA8aE-"><![CDATA[sampleresume.txt]]></FL>
<FL val="Photo (for CV)" type="url" url="https://recruit.zoho.com/ats/viewPhoto?filename=tVmTJJk2PIGQSgJSgY2fTzZfMgYE*W1ZBQ.KWiE6q685xDP3Iw.5GlcJtvxybS4bvD4mCWuA8aE-"><![CDATA[microsoft-gold-partner.png]]></FL>
<FL val="Candidate status"><![CDATA[New]]></FL></row></Candidates></result></response>
```

Comment: Have you already tried anything?

Comment: Yes but I can't figure out any thing. All the examples on internet are using different xml formats. So they don't work on my xml file.

Comment: You know, that the concept of XML is that they can be quite different.. What XML parser are you using? SimpleXML might be a start

Comment: I tried simple xml parser and another one but I am not quite familiar with this type of xml.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that I changed `<FL val="Role (if "Other")">` to `<FL val="Role (if &quot;Other&quot;)">` in order to be well-formed XML:

```
<?php

$result = <<<HERE
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>

<response uri="/ats/private/xml/Candidates/getRecords">
<result>
<Candidates>
<row no="1">
<FL val="RESUMEID"><![CDATA[93327000000109297]]></FL>
<FL val="Modified by"><![CDATA[Not specified]]></FL>
<FL val="Modified time"><![CDATA[Yesterday]]></FL>
<FL val="Candidate ID"><![CDATA[677]]></FL>
<FL val="First name"><![CDATA[TEst1]]></FL>
<FL val="Last name"><![CDATA[TEst2]]></FL>
<FL val="Residental Address"><![CDATA[TESTing res address]]></FL>
<FL val="Email ID"><![CDATA[test1@email.com]]></FL>
<FL val="Mobile Phone"><![CDATA[123456789]]></FL>
<FL val="Created On"><![CDATA[Yesterday]]></FL>
<FL val="Owner"><![CDATA[0]]></FL>
<FL val="Source"><![CDATA[Embed]]></FL>
<FL val="Employment Preference"><![CDATA[Contract (Full Time), Permanent (Full Time), Contract (Part Time), Permanent (Part Time)]]></FL>
<FL val="Cover Letter" type="url" url="https://recruit.zoho.com/ats/viewPhoto?filename=tVmTJJk2PIGQSgJSgY2fTzZfMgYE*W1ZBQ.KWiE6q68UOoUiAiY8ElcJtvxybS4bvD4mCWuA8aE-"><![CDATA[samplecoverletter.txt]]></FL>
<FL val="Total work exp (year)"><![CDATA[10]]></FL>
<FL val="Current Role"><![CDATA[Administrative Officer]]></FL>
<FL val="Current Role if Other"><![CDATA[current_role_if_other]]></FL>
<FL val="Current Employer/Customer"><![CDATA[Current_employer_name]]></FL>
<FL val="Skill sets"><![CDATA[skill_sets_goes_here]]></FL>
<FL val="Roles"><![CDATA[Consultant, 93327000000068819, Administrative Officer, Application Developer, Business Analyst, Change Manager, Business Development, Chief Technology Officer, Chief Information Officer, Chief Executive Officer, Data Analyst, Director, IT Manager, Implementation Mgr, Functional Analyst, PMO Manager, Other, Network Admin, Portfolio Manager, Program Manager, Project Admin, Project Manager (Jnr), Project Lead, Project Director, Project Manager (Mid), Project Manager (Snr/Principal), Project Officer, Project Scheduler, Service Delivery Mgr, Release Manager, Quality Manager, Solutions Architect, Systems / Technical Analyst, Systems Administrator, Technical Support, Technical Architect, Systems Engineer, Test Analyst, Test Manager]]></FL>
<FL val="Role (if &quot;Other&quot;)"><![CDATA[Role_other]]></FL>
<FL val="Industries"><![CDATA[93327000000068909, 93327000000070037, Aviation, Consulting, Contact Centres, Construction / Engineering, Council, Defense, Education, Energy, Finance/Banking, Gaming, Government, Health / Medical, Hospitality, ICT, Insurance, Manufacturing, Media, Mining, Other, Rail, Retail, Phamacetical, Telecommunications, Transportation, Utilities]]></FL><FL val="Expected Rate/Salary"><![CDATA[147852369]]></FL>
<FL val="Qualifications, Credentials, Memberships"><![CDATA[93327000000068871, 93327000000101075, AABA Membership, Agile PM Certification, AIPM   Membership, CMI Membership, Degree, IIBA Membership, ITIL, Masters Degree, MBA, MSP, PMI Membership, PMP, PRINCE2, RegPM]]></FL>
<FL val="Additional Information"><![CDATA[addational_information_goes_here]]></FL>
<FL val="Attach resume" type="url" url="https://recruit.zoho.com/ats/viewPhoto?filename=tVmTJJk2PIGQSgJSgY2fTzZfMgYE*W1ZBQ.KWiE6q69pGZ2uc5*.nlcJtvxybS4bvD4mCWuA8aE-"><![CDATA[sampleresume.txt]]></FL>
<FL val="Photo (for CV)" type="url" url="https://recruit.zoho.com/ats/viewPhoto?filename=tVmTJJk2PIGQSgJSgY2fTzZfMgYE*W1ZBQ.KWiE6q685xDP3Iw.5GlcJtvxybS4bvD4mCWuA8aE-"><![CDATA[microsoft-gold-partner.png]]></FL>
<FL val="Candidate status"><![CDATA[New]]></FL></row></Candidates></result></response>
HERE;

// First deal with problem with Simple XML and CDATA
$sxo = simplexml_load_string($result, null, LIBXML_NOCDATA);

// Use these two lines instead of the above line if you are forced to use PHP < 5.1.0 or LibXML < 2.6.0
// $result = preg_replace("/\<\!\[CDATA\[(.*?)\]\]\>/ies", 'htmlspecialchars("$1")', $result);
// $sxo = simplexml_load_string($result);


// Find First name
$fn = $sxo->xpath('//FL[@val="First name"]');

// Set the child content
$fn[0][0] = "Here's a new name";

// Show XML
print_r(htmlentities($sxo->asXML()));

?>
```

Comment: You are a Genius... Thanks this is working just like I wanted. Thanks a lot.

Comment: freddy K.'s post brought to my attention the LIBXML_NOCDATA argument available since PHP 5.1, which I incorporated into the code, as that is cleaner (and the CDATA replacement code suffers from a PHP quirk in preg_replace which adds backslashes to quotes with the 'e' modifier--which you could strip, but it gets cumbersome and error prone). I highly advise using my amended code instead.

Comment: Can you please tell me how to add new node like I want to add <FL val="Middle name"><![CDATA[TEst3]]></FL> in this xml. Tell me how to add this in above xml file.

Comment: If you mean add it programmatically, you should read up on SimpleXML at http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php or http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php . For the latter, you could use DOMNode::insertBefore, but you have to convert the simple XML into DOM. You really need to read up on these two.

Answer (score 3):

[SimpleXML](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php) (usually built into PHP 5) or any of the [other XML libraries](http://www.php.net/manual/en/refs.xml.php) listed in the PHP manual should help you out.

Comment: Please give me a small example I tried everything read on php.net, w3schools and on other websites. But they cant work on my xml.

Comment: You can load a file using [simplexml_load_file](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-file.php), or from a string by using the class' constructor. Then you may want to iterate over the children by using the [children](http://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.children.php) method, or run an XPath query using the [xpath](http://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.xpath.php) method to get to the elements you want.

Answer (score 2):

Using SimpleXML you have the XML as Object and can iterate over the entities:

```
$test = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>

<response uri="/ats/private/xml/Candidates/getRecords">
<result>
<Candidates>
<row no="1">
<FL val="RESUMEID"><![CDATA[93327000000109297]]></FL>
<FL val="Modified by"><![CDATA[Not specified]]></FL>
<FL val="Modified time"><![CDATA[Yesterday]]></FL>
<FL val="Candidate ID"><![CDATA[677]]></FL>
<FL val="First name"><![CDATA[TEst1]]></FL>
<FL val="Last name"><![CDATA[TEst2]]></FL>
<FL val="Residental Address"><![CDATA[TESTing res address]]></FL>
<FL val="Email ID"><![CDATA[test1@email.com]]></FL>
<FL val="Mobile Phone"><![CDATA[123456789]]></FL>
<FL val="Created On"><![CDATA[Yesterday]]></FL>
<FL val="Owner"><![CDATA[0]]></FL>
<FL val="Source"><![CDATA[Embed]]></FL>
<FL val="Employment Preference"><![CDATA[Contract (Full Time), Permanent (Full Time), Contract (Part Time), Permanent (Part Time)]]></FL>
<FL val="Cover Letter" type="url" url="https://recruit.zoho.com/ats/viewPhoto?filename=tVmTJJk2PIGQSgJSgY2fTzZfMgYE*W1ZBQ.KWiE6q68UOoUiAiY8ElcJtvxybS4bvD4mCWuA8aE-"><![CDATA[samplecoverletter.txt]]></FL>
<FL val="Total work exp (year)"><![CDATA[10]]></FL>
<FL val="Current Role"><![CDATA[Administrative Officer]]></FL>
<FL val="Current Role if Other"><![CDATA[current_role_if_other]]></FL>
<FL val="Current Employe Customer"><![CDATA[Current_employer_name]]></FL>
<FL val="Skill sets"><![CDATA[skill_sets_goes_here]]></FL>
<FL val="Roles"><![CDATA[Consultant, 93327000000068819, Administrative Officer, Application Developer, Business Analyst, Change Manager, Business Development, Chief Technology Officer, Chief Information Officer, Chief Executive Officer, Data Analyst, Director, IT Manager, Implementation Mgr, Functional Analyst, PMO Manager, Other, Network Admin, Portfolio Manager, Program Manager, Project Admin, Project Manager (Jnr), Project Lead, Project Director, Project Manager (Mid), Project Manager (Snr/Principal), Project Officer, Project Scheduler, Service Delivery Mgr, Release Manager, Quality Manager, Solutions Architect, Systems / Technical Analyst, Systems Administrator, Technical Support, Technical Architect, Systems Engineer, Test Analyst, Test Manager]]></FL>
<FL val="Role (if Other)"><![CDATA[Role_other]]></FL>
<FL val="Industries"><![CDATA[93327000000068909, 93327000000070037, Aviation, Consulting, Contact Centres, Construction / Engineering, Council, Defense, Education, Energy, Finance/Banking, Gaming, Government, Health / Medical, Hospitality, ICT, Insurance, Manufacturing, Media, Mining, Other, Rail, Retail, Phamacetical, Telecommunications, Transportation, Utilities]]></FL><FL val="Expected Rate/Salary"><![CDATA[147852369]]></FL>
<FL val="Qualifications, Credentials, Memberships"><![CDATA[93327000000068871, 93327000000101075, AABA Membership, Agile PM Certification, AIPM   Membership, CMI Membership, Degree, IIBA Membership, ITIL, Masters Degree, MBA, MSP, PMI Membership, PMP, PRINCE2, RegPM]]></FL>
<FL val="Additional Information"><![CDATA[addational_information_goes_here]]></FL>
<FL val="Attach resume" type="url" url="https://recruit.zoho.com/ats/viewPhoto?filename=tVmTJJk2PIGQSgJSgY2fTzZfMgYE*W1ZBQ.KWiE6q69pGZ2uc5*.nlcJtvxybS4bvD4mCWuA8aE-"><![CDATA[sampleresume.txt]]></FL>
<FL val="Photo (for CV)" type="url" url="https://recruit.zoho.com/ats/viewPhoto?filename=tVmTJJk2PIGQSgJSgY2fTzZfMgYE*W1ZBQ.KWiE6q685xDP3Iw.5GlcJtvxybS4bvD4mCWuA8aE-"><![CDATA[microsoft-gold-partner.png]]></FL>
<FL val="Candidate status"><![CDATA[New]]></FL>
</row>
</Candidates>
</result>
</response>';

$xml = simplexml_load_string($test, null, LIBXML_NOCDATA);

foreach($xml->result->Candidates as $candidate){
    foreach($candidate->row->FL as $FL){
        print "Attributes:\n";
        foreach($FL->attributes() as $attribute => $value){
            print $attribute .':'.$value."\n";
        }
        print "Value:\n";
        print (string)$FL."\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks your solutions is also very good. I m using it in combination with brettz9's solution. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how you want to do this. You can do it server-side or you can do it using javascript. In case of server side, you can try doing it by using PHP..here is an [article about it](http://www.criticaldevelopment.net/xml/doc.php). In javascript, you do it by opening the xml file and then calling the XMLhttprequest to retrieve access to the DOM elements in the XML file :

```
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();//for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
else
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");//for IE

xmlhttp.open("GET","your_file.xml",false);
xmlhttp.send();
xmlDoc=xmlhttp.responseXML;
```

That code above will open the XML file and the XML file will send a response containing the DOM info of the file back to xmlDoc..

Why dont you show what you have done so far since we can help you better that way

Comment: ehm, maybe He need a php solution, not a javascript one ... ;)

Comment: my bad, didnt see the PHP tag. there is a lot of online references out there about XML parsing with PHP, I think his question will be resolved soon..

Answer (score 1):

Use this code

```
function xml2array($contents, $get_attributes=1, $priority = 'tag') {
    if(!$contents) return array();

    if(!function_exists('xml_parser_create')) {
        //print "'xml_parser_create()' function not found!";
        return array();
    }

    //Get the XML parser of PHP - PHP must have this module for the parser to work
    $parser = xml_parser_create('');
    xml_parser_set_option($parser, XML_OPTION_TARGET_ENCODING, "UTF-8"); # http://minutillo.com/steve/weblog/2004/6/17/php-xml-and-character-encodings-a-tale-of-sadness-rage-and-data-loss
    xml_parser_set_option($parser, XML_OPTION_CASE_FOLDING, 0);
    xml_parser_set_option($parser, XML_OPTION_SKIP_WHITE, 1);
    xml_parse_into_struct($parser, trim($contents), $xml_values);
    xml_parser_free($parser);

    if(!$xml_values) return; //Hmm...

    //Initializations
    $xml_array = array();
    $parents = array();
    $opened_tags = array();
    $arr = array();

    $current = &$xml_array; //Refference

    //Go through the tags.
    $repeated_tag_index = array(); //Multiple tags with same name will be turned into an array
    foreach($xml_values as $data) {
        unset($attributes,$value); //Remove existing values, or there will be trouble

        //This command will extract these variables into the foreach scope
        // tag(string), type(string), level(int), attributes(array).
        extract($data); //We could use the array by itself, but this cooler.

        $result = array();
        $attributes_data = array();

        if(isset($value)) {
            if($priority == 'tag') $result = $value;
            else $result['value'] = $value; //Put the value in a assoc array if we are in the 'Attribute' mode
        }

        //Set the attributes too.
        if(isset($attributes) and $get_attributes) {
            foreach($attributes as $attr => $val) {
                if($priority == 'tag') $attributes_data[$attr] = $val;
                else $result['attr'][$attr] = $val; //Set all the attributes in a array called 'attr'
            }
        }

        //See tag status and do the needed.
        if($type == "open") { //The starting of the tag ''
            $parent[$level-1] = &$current;
            if(!is_array($current) or (!in_array($tag, array_keys($current)))) { //Insert New tag
                $current[$tag] = $result;
                if($attributes_data) $current[$tag. '_attr'] = $attributes_data;
                $repeated_tag_index[$tag.'_'.$level] = 1;

                $current = &$current[$tag];

            } else { //There was another element with the same tag name

            if(isset($current[$tag][0])) { //If there is a 0th element it is already an array
                $current[$tag][$repeated_tag_index[$tag.'_'.$level]] = $result;
                $repeated_tag_index[$tag.'_'.$level]++;
            } else { //This section will make the value an array if multiple tags with the same name appear together
                $current[$tag] = array($current[$tag],$result);//This will combine the existing item and the new item together to make an array
                $repeated_tag_index[$tag.'_'.$level] = 2;

                if(isset($current[$tag.'_attr'])) { //The attribute of the last(0th) tag must be moved as well
                    $current[$tag]['0_attr'] = $current[$tag.'_attr'];
                    unset($current[$tag.'_attr']);
                }

            }
            $last_item_index = $repeated_tag_index[$tag.'_'.$level]-1;
            $current = &$current[$tag][$last_item_index];
        }

    } elseif($type == "complete") { //Tags that ends in 1 line ''
        //See if the key is already taken.
        if(!isset($current[$tag])) { //New Key
        $current[$tag] = $result;
        $repeated_tag_index[$tag.'_'.$level] = 1;
        if($priority == 'tag' and $attributes_data) $current[$tag. '_attr'] = $attributes_data;

        } else { //If taken, put all things inside a list(array)
            if(isset($current[$tag][0]) and is_array($current[$tag])) { //If it is already an array...

            // ...push the new element into that array.
            $current[$tag][$repeated_tag_index[$tag.'_'.$level]] = $result;

            if($priority == 'tag' and $get_attributes and $attributes_data) {
                $current[$tag][$repeated_tag_index[$tag.'_'.$level] . '_attr'] = $attributes_data;
            }
            $repeated_tag_index[$tag.'_'.$level]++;

            } else { //If it is not an array...
                $current[$tag] = array($current[$tag],$result); //...Make it an array using using the existing value and the new value
                $repeated_tag_index[$tag.'_'.$level] = 1;
                if($priority == 'tag' and $get_attributes) {
                    if(isset($current[$tag.'_attr'])) { //The attribute of the last(0th) tag must be moved as well

                    $current[$tag]['0_attr'] = $current[$tag.'_attr'];
                    unset($current[$tag.'_attr']);
                }

                if($attributes_data) {
                    $current[$tag][$repeated_tag_index[$tag.'_'.$level] . '_attr'] = $attributes_data;
                    }
                }
                $repeated_tag_index[$tag.'_'.$level]++; //0 and 1 index is already taken
                }
            }
        } elseif($type == 'close') { //End of tag ''
        $current = &$parent[$level-1];
        }
    }
    return($xml_array);
}
```